# MathJax not displayed in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mathjax, comment, android-app

In the Android App, the MathJax is not displayed correctly in **comments** to answers.

I assume this also applies to comments the question, but I have not verified that.

[image]

Comment: Can you link the original question?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282646/calculate-total-arc-length-of-spherical-cap-of-a-specified-circumference

Comment: please note that this is for the Android App only. It is all comments on Any question.

Comment: See also [Android app doesn't render LaTeX content in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244860/android-app-doesnt-render-latex-content-in-comments) and [Easier mechanism to display MathJax in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/easier-mechanism-to-display-mathjax-in-comments) on meta.SE.

Comment: I had the exact same question. I honestly don't know why the comments do not automatically render MathJax. Maybe for space saving sake? I don't know. **Edit**: a probable reason I read on **meta** is that it would slow down the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This is by design, you can tap on a comment to view the MathJax rendering. We should definitely get better at explaining this, however.

— [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251465/259867) (SE mobile team lead)

Comment: OK, but that is very intuitive. Never in my rightful mind would I have though...tap>>click drop-down>> click render

Comment: could there be an option to render the MathJax next to the time?

Comment: I don't know; feel free to make a feature request at [meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: if $r_0=1km$, then $d=(π/2)km$ ? –  Christopher Rucinski 3 hours ago *render MathJax*

Comment: OK, I will do that

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/easier-mechanism-to-display-mathjax-in-comments