# Mobile phone Latex/MathJax not showing in..

Tags: support, mathjax, comment, titles, android-app

Is there a way to see full symbols in Titles and Comments using  equations and expressions?  Thanks.

Comment: You might say more about the mobile phone OS which the app you use is for.

Comment: One plus 3 Oxygen OS.

Comment: Thanks, so naturally you have the Android version.

Comment: Here is a related older question: [MathJax not displayed in comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20515). (The answer was posted in 2017, so it might be outdated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should be visible when viewing the site in a browser. If you mean using the mobile app, note that the mobile apps are no longer supported. However, you can tap on a comment and select an option to view the rendered mathjax. [There is no such option for titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221927/279167).

If it's not visible on the mobile site with the blue theme, you can select full site with a link at the bottom and you will get the responsive design, which is much like the full site on the desktop but with appropriate sizing for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks. I could get to see comments rendered in Mathjax. Wonder why titles are not not made renderable as well.

Comment: @Narasimham FWIW, on my Samsung Android phone, using the Samsung browser in `full site` mode, MathJax is *mostly* visible in titles & previews on the Questions page (I never use the front page). But sometimes the MathJax stops being rendered in the titles & previews. I *think* that happens when the page shows that banner saying there's "n questions with new activity". If you click that banner the new titles & previews don't render their MathJax. But the MathJax comes back after a full page refresh. So just don't click that banner! ;)

Comment: Thanks. OK then, I shall also try refreshing.. even switching off to coax  it to appear in titles as well.